# rails validation error in regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have used regular form for validating first name field. It allow only letters but not allowing spaces. I have used like

```
validates :first_name,    presence: true,
                         format: { with:/\A[a-z_]+\Z/, message: 'Only letters are allowed' }
```

If I give `abc asd` in first name field. It shows message like "only letters allowed"

Comment: "abc asd" contains spaces

Comment: what do you want the regex to validate?

Comment: Please give us sample input and sample output.

Comment: obviously, s?he wants to add spaces to the allowed list which is quite ironic since it's damn easy: just add a space in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces aren't letters.

Do you want to allow spaces in the first name field? If so you need to add a space to your list of things to test: `\A[a-z_ ]+\Z`

Also.. your users won't be able to use capitals for their name. If you want to allow capital letters use `\A[a-zA-Z_ ]+\Z`

Hope this helps.